# How do I change the learning rate of my readout layer? (PyTorch)

Tags: pytorch

I found how to change the learning rate for a specific layer, but I'm not sure if I have the right thing.

Here I have a single-layer nn and I'm trying to change the learning rate for the readout weights.

I suppose that the "relu1" would be where I could access the readout weights but I'm not sure.

```
class NN(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, input_size, num_classes):

        super(NN, self).__init__()
        self.path1 = nn.Linear(input_size, num_classes)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.path1(x)
        x = self.relu1(x)

        return x
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a bit confused. You don't need to place the learning rate parameter inside your neural net. Instead, go through the [Per-Parameter Option](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#per-parameter-options) while defining your optimizer. You can write the parameter name by printing out your model and specifying the particular parameter you want to change.

Cheers ;)

Comment: Yea that's what I plan on doing. My question is if I'm trying to change the learning rate for the readout layer which layers lr do I change?

Comment: It seems you are using NN for classification. in that case, You have to add another layer after ReLU and make the output on that layer as `num_classes`. And you can control lr till the ReLU layer.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I should have added more context, I am using this for classification. I see what you're saying. Do you know of a way to create such a layer?